# Searching for Id in MySql from an array using For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

I have an array of `tag names` which I passed via `POST Method` and I these tag names has its corresponding `tag_id` in the database. All I want is to search the id while iterating the array of tag names and I want the result of each query to be stored in an empty array. I think I just misunderstood something or what.

```
$tags_array = ['shoes','gadgets','fashion','food'];
$tags_array_id = [];
$tags_sql = '';

foreach ($tags_array as &$tag) {
    $sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM `tbltag` WHERE tag_name = ".$tag." group by tag_name";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $tags_array_id[] = $result[0];
};
```

Please help guys, suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to run a single query, using the sql keyword `in` and loop through the results.

Comment: I will try sir. Thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: I don't see the $_POST data you are using there. You might want to review PHP's implode function.  Also, you should probably use one query. Look at MySQL's IN() function.

Comment: your query doesn't run because `$tag` isn't quoted. if `$tags_array` comes from user input you're vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I just make the `$tags_array` static on the question material because its fetched from db. Many to mention. But thanks by the way (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
$tags_array = ['shoes','gadgets','fashion','food'];
$tags = implode("','", $tags_array);
$tags = "'".$tags."'";
$sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM tbltag WHERE tag_name IN ({$tags})";
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbltag` WHERE tag_name IN('".implode("','", $tags_array)."')";
```

One last comment: You probably want to search for tag_id's instead of tag names, as you'll probably have those in your input ($_POST/$_GET). And as FuzzyTree has mentioned above, you'll want some type of ID validation and some kind of escaping of data going into the query to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Do you need the & in your foreach loop? You are not directly modifying the tags_array just using the information?

Trying adding the number to the array e.g add $x so you are adding in 1 record into 1 part of the array as you loop though.

```
$tags_array = ['shoes','gadgets','fashion','food'];
$tags_array_id = [];
$tags_sql = '';
$x = 0;

foreach ($tags_array as &$tag) {
    $sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM `tbltag` WHERE tag_name = ".$tag." group by tag_name";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $tags_array_id[$x] = $result[0];
    $x++;
};
```